# How to log route for every url?

Tags: magento2, router

I am trying to get the list of routers and followed [this](https://github.com/czettnersandor/magento2-list-all-available-routers) available module, but I am trying to get the router for every url that executed on the browser.

In the code as shown below.

```
foreach ($this->_routerList as $router) {
      $ret .= get_class($router)."\n";
}
```

is giving me routes only for this module, where as I want for all the urls.

Comment: what's the purpose of this? could you share?

Comment: purpose is to see which router is triggered on the frontend and whats the class of that object